# Allowance failed when attempting to transfer LINK tokens

Tags: solidity, blockchain, chainlink, allowance, chainlink-vrf

I'm creating a smart contract where users can create NFT raffles. I will be using Chainlink VRF for getting provably fair results. For this, the user who creates the raffle needs to supply the contract with LINK tokens. I'm attempting to transfer these tokens using an allowance.

```
  function initRaffle(address _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _ticketPrice) external {
      require(_ticketPrice > 0, "Ticket price must be bigger than 0");
      require(LINKToken.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= ChainlinkFee, "Insufficient LINK supplied");
      require(LINKToken.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= ChainlinkFee, "Allowance failed");
```

Running `initRaffle` results in `Allowance failed`. I've checked and the `LINKToken.balanceOf(msg.sender)` is bigger than the fee, so that shouldn't be the problem. The `LINKToken.balanceOf(address(this))` is 0.

What's going wrong? And how do I create a working function for having the user transfer (fee amount) link tokens to the contract.

Comment: Did you set the allowance for how many LINK tokens the contract can take from you? By the way you should just transfer the tokens. The token's transferFrom already checks these things and you are wasting gas by checking them twice.

Answer (score 1):

Did you call approve() function of the LINK token from the msg.sender address?

Allowance is increased by calling approve() on the LINK contract to increase the allowance.
If your check fails there, it means the allowance is < than ChainLink fee. So the address of the user need to first call the approve() function of the link contract.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I call this `approve` function from the smart contract / remix? I've tried `LINKToken.approve(msg.sender, (0.1 * 10 ** 18));` Before the require statements, but this didn't work?

Comment: @TRS **Your account** (the one giving the tokens) has to call it to say you are okay with the contract taking a certain number of tokens from you.

Comment: Either copy the code from the etherscan page of the deployed link erc20 or use any erc20 compliant contract and use "load contract from address". But you need to call the approve() function from the user address